# Unable to inject SecurityContext with services

Tags: php, symfony

I've seen a lot of posts about this, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

services.yml:

```
parameters:

services:
    bar.menu_builder:
        class: Foo\BarBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
        arguments: [ @security.context ]
```

MenuBuilder:

```
namespace Foo\BarBundle\Menu;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;

class MenuBuilder {

    protected $securityContext;
    protected $isLoggedIn;

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext) {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->isLoggedIn = $this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
    }

    // other methods
}
```

But there is no SecurityContext passed, because I get this exception:

> **ContextErrorException**: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Foo\BarBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface, **none given**

Any idea?

Comment: Just for my curiosity, as I've seen this error many times and every time is the same issue that cause this, how do you retrieve your bar.menu_builder service? Could you give us a snippet of relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to fully understrand why I was having this issue (I'm still a beginner with Symfony2), but I've managed to solved it.

I've added another service to render my menu (see [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/menu_service.md)):

```
bar.menu.main:
    class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem # the service definition requires setting the class
    factory_service: bar.menu_builder
    factory_method: createMainMenu
    arguments: ["@knp_menu.factory"]
    scope: request # needed as we have the request as a dependency here
    tags:
      - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: main } # The alias is what is used to retrieve the menu
```

And changed:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('BarBundle:MenuBuilder:createMainMenu') }}
```

For:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main') }}
```

I think that, as suggested by @Steffen Brem and @DonCallisto, `bar.menu_builder` was just never retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

Service arguments should be quoted.

```
parameters:

services:
    bar.menu_builder:
        class: Foo\BarBundle\Menu\MenuBuilder
        arguments: ["@security.context"]
```

Comment: Try clearing cache. Or check if you imported your services.yml

Answer (score 1):

Did you import the security.yml in your config.yml? Like so:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
```

Also, you have to get your object trough the container, like so:

```
$this->get('bar.menu_builder');
```

If this does not work, then you can try to empty your cache, so it will recompile the container.

Steffen